# Comparing two email addresses in PHP/MySQL always returns false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to register users from a unique invite code link which is checked against their email address. At registration I'm running a check to see if the email address they posted matches the email we have stored in the database. Everything seems to be running great, I have validated the email and codes being sent to the check function, but for some reason this continually returns false. What am I missing here?

```
public function CheckEmail($email, $code, $db) 
    {

        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT 'email' FROM `userlogin` WHERE `code`= ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $code, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        try
        {

            $query->execute();
            $data = $query->fetch();
            $confirmEmail = $data['email'];


            if($confirmEmail == $email)
            {
            return true;
            }

            else
            {
            return false;
            }

        } 

        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- he is using a paramterised query, so no.

Comment: @Shamil I deleted my comment. thanks

Comment: @Fred-ii- no need to delete your comment :(

Comment: @Shamil I deleted it because it was irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to to

```
"SELECT `email` FROM `userlogin` WHERE `code`= ?"
```

You wrapped email in single quote marks and not back ticks, hence you were really selecting the text `email` to compare against

Comment: @DrGraves Please mark it as solved (there should be a green checkmark under the voting arrow) :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check if they are of the same data type ? also if you have phpmyadmin try running the query manually to see what it returns. You might be suprised and find that you did not have the expected result.