# Ionic 2: Validate Email if already exists in the database(API)

Tags: angular, api, validation, ionic2

I wanted to validate the username if it already exists in my database. Here is my code:`

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class EmailValidator {

  static checkEmail(control: FormControl): any {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        let EMAIL_REGEXP = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)*$/i;

        if (control.value != "" && (control.value.length <= 5 || !EMAIL_REGEXP.test(control.value))) { 

          resolve({
            "Please provide a valid email": true
          });

        }else if(control.value.toLowerCase() === "sample123@yahoo.com"){

          resolve({
            "email taken": true
          });

        }else {
          resolve(null);
        }

    });
  }

}
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: else if(control.value.toLowerCase() === "sample123@yahoo.com") this code checks if the sample123@yahoo.com can never be used. I want to replace it from my API.

Comment: No, MySQL. I have API.

Answer (score 0):

The logic could resume to the following concept (roughly) :

**Form Validation**

```
this.authService.registerEmail(email).subscribe(data => {
  if (data.success) {
     //server answered that the email doesn' exist
     showSucces();
     doSomthingHere(); //route? 
  }
  else{
    //failed, email exists
    showFail();
    doReturnToTheForm(); //route back
  }
```

and

**AuthService**

```
  registerEmail(email) {
    return this.dataService.postData(someUrl, email);
  }
```

where dataService is making http POST request managed by a backend server.

**dataService**

```
 constructor(private http:Http)
    postData(dataUrl: string, body: any): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: this.getHeaders(null) })
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch((res: Response) => this.errorManager(res));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by creating an Api and passing email in request. In response you will get the success or error from serve side.
You cant handle it without an Api call.

Comment: Thank you. But what exactly I'm going to do if I already have my API. How will I compare the inputted email from the email that already exists in my API.

Comment: If you are using MYSQL you can use as it is done here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670326/comparing-two-email-addresses-in-php-mysql-always-returns-false

Comment: I am using Angular 2 and JSON API